# dbf CREATE TABLE throws java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at 

Tags: java, sql, database, dbf

I have a dbf file, and I can see in the view that types of intersting fields are L ( I suppose it is logical type ) and M (I suppose it's a Memo type)

I try to recreate dbf template using dbf_jdbc, like table:

```
 private static final String TABLE = "create table SAMPLE ( "
          + "   SM Logical, "
          + "   PRIM  MEMO " + ")";
...
String url = "jdbc:DBF:/C:\\TEST";
Connection dbfConn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
...
// instantiate it
Class.forName( "com.hxtt.sql.dbf.DBFDriver" ).newInstance();
dbfConn = DriverManager.getConnection( url, properties );
Statement stmt = dbfConn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE);
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at MEMO
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at LOGICAL
```

The reason - type names, because when I use varchar, everythins is fine.

Dbf_jdbc version (from jar manifest file):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: HXTT Version Robot
Main-Class: com.hxtt.sql.admin.Admin

Name: com/hxtt/sql/dbf/
Specification-Title: HXTT DBF JDBC 3.0 Package
Implementation-Title: com.hxtt.sql.dbf
Specification-Version: 4.2.056 on April 01, 2009
Specification-Vendor: Hongxin Technology & Trade Ltd.
Comment: JDBC 3.0 Package for Xbase database
Implementation-Version: 4.2.056 on April 01, 2009
Implementation-Vendor: Hongxin Technology & Trade Ltd.
Implementation-URL: http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html

Name: com/hxtt/sql/admin/
Specification-Title: HXTT Database Admin
Implementation-Title: com.hxtt.sql.admin
Specification-Vendor: Hongxin Technology & Trade Ltd.
Specification-Version: 0.5 on April 01, 2009
Comment: HXTT Database Admin
Implementation-Version: 0.5 on April 01, 2009
Implementation-Vendor: Hongxin Technology & Trade Ltd.
Implementation-URL: http://www.hxtt.com/dbf/dbadmin.html
```

So my question is **which sql type should I use so I could create dbf template using code and when I open a file using dbf viewer I could see letters M and L as type shortnames.**

Comment: Older versions of dbf didn't have memo fields. Are you sure, your versions match?

Comment: I've added version infor. Where can I find information about versions and supported types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create table SAMPLE ( "
+ " SM BIT , "
+ " PRIM longvarchar" + ")";

SQL Data Types for Create Table at http://www.hxtt.com/dbf/sqlsyntax.html#createtable

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the reason of the problem with dbf_jdbc. I used javadbf framework to create a template. The following example illustrates it:

```
File file = new File( filePathName );
DBFWriter dbfWriter = new DBFWriter( file );
dbfWriter.setCharactersetName( "cp866" );

DBFField[] fields = new DBFField[ 29 ];
fields[ 0 ] = new DBFField();
fields[ 0 ].setDataType( DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_L );
fields[ 0 ].setName( "SM" );
...
fields[ 19 ] = new DBFField();
fields[ 19 ].setDataType( DBFField.FIELD_TYPE_M );
fields[ 19 ].setName( "PRIM" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about java based dbc driver, but an implied abbreviated version is to just use "L" or "M" respectively

```
create table SAMPLE ( SM   L,  PRIM   M )";
```

Additionally for some other types

```
C(?) = character (?=length of character based field)
I = integer
D = date (only date portion)
T = date/time
B(?) = double(?=decimal precision -- ex: B(3) = up to 3 decimals )
```

Answer (score 0):

dBase III files support:

- Char        `name C(40)`
- Date        `birth D`
- Logical     `member L`
- Memo        `desc M`
- Numeric     `rate N(6, 2)`

The first letter of the type is what you want to use.

Additionally, other dbf formats allow:

- Currency    `price Y` (note `Y`, not `C`)
- DateTime    `appt T`  (note `T`, not `D`)
- Double      `mass B`  (note `B`, not `D`)
- Float       (same as Numeric)
- General     `bin_data G`
- Integer     `age I`
- Picture     `photo P`

Currency, Double, Integer, General, and Picture all store the data as binary, while the others store the data as text.

Comment: If you'll look at my code example you'll find that I'm trying to use Logical and Memo as types and i'm getting the "Stopped parse at MEMO" and "Stopped parse at LOGICAL" errors. The cause of this question is why I'm getting the errors alghough the types are supported.

Comment: @Alexandr:  Have you tried using `L` and `M` instead of `LOGICAL` and `MEMO`?

Comment: yes, I've tried, but got the same result:  "java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at L"

Comment: @Alexandr: Huh -- I have no other ideas.